# How to create a method in other class drawing on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

My goal: create a method of class Point (code at the bottom), that allows me to draw multiple points (and lines in the future), so it looks like this:

```
Point pointA = new Point(0,0);
Point pointB = new Point(10,20);
pointA.draw(); // or probably: pointA.draw(someSurface);
pointB.draw();
```

I took code from a [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/introduction/) and modified it.

I found many similar problems while searching for answer, but either none of them had the answer for my case or I couldn't implement it.

As you can see below, I tried to create the method both inside the Point class and inside the Surface class (commented code), but without success.

What is the problem and what should I fix in my code?

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BasicGraphics ex = new BasicGraphics();
                ex.setVisible(true);
                Point pointA = new Point(0,0);
                Point pointB = new Point(10,10);
                pointA.draw(ex.currentSurface);
                pointB.draw(ex.currentSurface);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BasicGraphics:

```
public class BasicGraphics extends JFrame {
    public Surface currentSurface;
    public BasicGraphics() {
        initUI();
    }
    private void initUI() {
        currentSurface=new Surface();
        add(currentSurface);
        setTitle("My points");
        setSize(100, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Surface:

```
class Surface extends JPanel {

    /*public void drawPoint(Graphics g, Point givenPoint) {
        //I want to represent points as little circles
        Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(); 
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        circle.setFrameFromCenter(givenPoint.x, givenPoint.y, 10,10);
        g2d.draw(circle);
    }*/
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

Point:

```
public class Point {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public Point(double newX, double newY){
        x=newX;
        y=newY;
    }

public void draw(Surface givenSurface){
    Graphics g = givenSurface.getGraphics();
    Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    circle.setFrameFromCenter(x, y, 10,10);
    g2d.draw(circle);
    givenSurface.paint(g2d);
    //givenSurface.drawPoint(g2d,this);
    //givenSurface.repaint();
    }
}
```

edit: Solutions, thanks to [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr). That's not the most elegant way I can imagine, but it works:

draw method in Point:

```
public void draw(Surface givenSurface){
        givenSurface.pointsList.add(this);
}
```

Surface class:

```
class Surface extends JPanel {

    public ArrayList<Point> pointsList = new ArrayList<>();

    private void drawPoints(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        double diameter = 10;
        for (Point currentPoint : pointsList) {
            Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(currentPoint.x - diameter / 2, currentPoint.y - diameter / 2, diameter, diameter);
            g2d.fill(circle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawPoints(g);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a method of class Point (code at the bottom), that allows me to draw multiple points (and lines in the future).

All custom painting needs to be done in the `paintComponent()` method of the panel. So every time the panel is painted the points/lines are repainted.

So if you want to paint multiple object you need to:

1. Create an ArrayList of the Object you want to paint
2. Create a method to add Objects to this list
3. In the paintComponent() method you iterate through the list and paint each Object.

Check out the `DrawOnCompont` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It shows how you can dynamically add Rectangle to be painted.

Comment: So as I understand, if I want to draw different points and lines in different styles I have to either:
1. Create multiple lists and inside paintComponent in each loop use different styles.
2. Create additional list storing style for each component. Or maybe a HashMap, or something like this.

Comment: @mstechly, you can store a `Shape` in the Arraylist. The you can use the `Graphics2D.draw(Shape)` method. So this means you could add a line, rectangle, ellipse, polygon to the same ArrayList because all those objects implement the Shape interface. You can even add more complex Shapes to the list. See [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `paintComponent` method will be invoked at `setVisible(true)` but you draw your Points after that, You have to repaint. See code modification.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BasicGraphics ex = new BasicGraphics();
                ex.setVisible(true);
                Point pointA = new Point(0,0);
                Point pointB = new Point(10,10);
                pointA.draw(ex.currentSurface);
                pointB.draw(ex.currentSurface);
                ex.revalidate();
                ex.repaint();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: First time I ran it it appeared for a moment and then disappeared. Now there is not even this short moment. Any idea?